# Unity EditorWindow modify the image in scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

My first question on stackoverflow. I'm nervous.
So I am working on some project and recently I recieved a task to create an EditorWindow tool to automatize workflow of creating different offers in game. There are several types of them but the bug showed up only at one.

The objective was simply to assign some Textures and name via EditorWindow that are needed to create new element, then press "create" button and script automaticly creates needed folders hierarchy, prefab variants, sprite atlasses and assigns appropriate Textures to appropriate Images.

The problem is that in one of the offer types it should just set the image to the background of the prefab but when you open it to check it's always blank. I tested other offers and they work fine, other prefabs have the nbackground image assigned to them and it works fine. I tried check what's wrong using debug mode.I put some breakpoints and there was no problem. Even more, if you try test this line by line with breakpoints it unexpectablybegins to work and you can't see the bug because everything is good. But if you turn breakpoints off prefab instantly becomes blank. I tried to test it with Debug.Log() at avery second line of code. And it worked fine. No nulls, no Errors. Nothing.

I've tried to google this but only one thing I found useful was SetDirty() method. And it's already there. It is used in SetAddressableGroup() method. But it still not working. I haven't even entered the game mode.

Here is my code and thank you for your replies.

## SingleOfferWindow class

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Menu = Common.Menu;

namespace Windows {
   public class SingleOfferWindow : OfferWindow {

       private Vector2 scrollPos;
       private SerializedObject so;

       private bool IsOfferReady => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(offerName) && shortcut != null && background != null;

       [MenuItem("MyCompany/Offers/Single")]
       private static void Init() {
           var window = GetWindow<SingleOfferWindow>("Single");
           window.autoRepaintOnSceneChange = true;
           window.Show();
       }

       private void OnEnable() {
           so = new SerializedObject(this);
       }

       private void OnGUI() {
           EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
           EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos);
           #region Properties
           EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(so.FindProperty("offerName"), true);
           EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(so.FindProperty("shortcut"), true);
           EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(so.FindProperty("background"), true);
           so.ApplyModifiedProperties();
           #endregion
           EditorGUILayout.Space();
           if (!IsOfferReady) {
               EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("Name or texture missing", MessageType.Error);
           }
           
           EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(!IsOfferReady);
           EditorGUILayout.Space();
           GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
           EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
           GUILayout.Button("----->", GUILayout.Height(50));
           EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
           
           var backgroundColor = GUI.backgroundColor;
           GUI.backgroundColor = Color.green;
           if (GUILayout.Button("Create Offer", GUILayout.Width(100), GUILayout.Height(50))) {
               CreateOffer();
           }
           GUI.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
           
           EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
           GUILayout.Button("<-----", GUILayout.Height(50));
           EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
           GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
           EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
           EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
           EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
       }

       protected override void CreateOffer() {
           //find and create folder for current offer
           var offerPath = Directory.Exists($"{root_offers_path}/{single_folder}/{offerName}")
               ? $"{root_offers_path}/{single_folder}/{offerName}"
               : AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(AssetDatabase.CreateFolder($"{root_offers_path}/{single_folder}", offerName));
           //create base folders hierarchy
           CreateFolders(offerPath);
           //create and remember images folders
           var shortcutImagesPath = Directory.Exists($"{offerPath}/{shortcut_folder_name}/{images_folder_name}/{images_uncompressed}")
               ? $"{offerPath}/{shortcut_folder_name}/{images_folder_name}/{images_uncompressed}"
               : Menu.CreateSpriteAtlas($"{offerPath}/{shortcut_folder_name}/{images_folder_name}", images_uncompressed);
           var dialogCompressedImagesPath = Directory.Exists($"{offerPath}/{dialog_folder_name}/{images_folder_name}/{images_compressed}")
               ? $"{offerPath}/{dialog_folder_name}/{images_folder_name}/{images_compressed}"
               : Menu.CreateSpriteAtlas($"{offerPath}/{dialog_folder_name}/{images_folder_name}", images_compressed);

           MoveTexture(shortcut, shortcutImagesPath, string.Join("_", (offerName + shortcut_icon_name).ToLower().Split(" ")));
           MoveTexture(background, dialogCompressedImagesPath, pack_bg_name);

           var prefab = CreatePrefabVariant(shortcut_base_path, $"{offerPath}/{offerName}{shortcut_prefab_name}");
           var img = prefab.transform.Find("Content/Background").GetComponent<Image>();
           SetProperty(img, "m_Sprite", AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>($"{shortcutImagesPath}/{string.Join("_", (offerName + shortcut_icon_name).ToLower().Split(" "))}.png"));
           SetAddressableGroup(prefab, $"All/{offerName}Shortcut", "RemoteProductsShortcuts");

           prefab = CreatePrefabVariant(single_base_path, $"{offerPath}/{offerName}{dialog_prefab_name}");
           img = prefab.transform.Find("Content/Background").GetComponent<Image>();
           SetProperty(img, "m_Sprite", AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>($"{dialogCompressedImagesPath}/{pack_bg_name}.png"));
           SetAddressableGroup(prefab, $"All/{offerName}Dialog", "RemoteProductsDialogs");
       }
   }
}
```

## OfferWindow class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Common;
using DG.DemiEditor;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.AddressableAssets;
using UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Settings;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class OfferWindow : EditorWindow {
    public string offerName;
    public Texture2D shortcut;
    public Texture2D background;

    #region Paths

    protected const string multiple_1_of_2_folder = "Multiple1Of2";
    protected const string multiple_1_of_3_folder = "Multiple1Of3";
    protected const string multiple_1_plus_1_folder = "Multiple1Plus1";
    protected const string multiple_1_plus_2_folder = "Multiple1Plus2";
    protected const string multiple3_folder = "Multiple3";
    protected const string multiple6_folder = "Multiple6";
    protected const string single_folder = "Single";

    protected const string dialog_folder_name = "Dialog";
    protected const string shortcut_folder_name = "Shortcut";
    protected const string images_folder_name = "Images";
    
    protected const string root_offers_path = "Assets/Content/Remote/Products";
    protected const string shortcut_base_path = "Assets/Content/Remote/Products/BasePrefabs/OfferShortcutBase.prefab";
    protected const string single_base_path = "Assets/Content/Remote/Products/BasePrefabs/Single/ProductDialogBase.prefab";
    protected const string multiple3_base_path = "Assets/Content/Remote/Products/BasePrefabs/Vertical/MultipleProductVerticalDialogBase.prefab";
    protected const string multiple6_base_path = "Assets/Content/Remote/Products/BasePrefabs/Grid/GridProductMatrixDialogBase.prefab";
    protected const string horizontal_one_base_path = "Assets/Content/Remote/Products/BasePrefabs/Horizontal/MultipleProductHorizontalOneDialogBase.prefab";
    protected const string horizontal_plus_base_path = "Assets/Content/Remote/Products/BasePrefabs/Horizontal/MultipleProductHorizontalPlusDialogBase.prefab";

    #endregion

    #region Constants

    protected const string images_compressed = "Compressed";
    protected const string images_uncompressed = "Uncompressed";

    protected const string shortcut_icon_name = "_icon";
    protected const string top_picture_name = "_top_picture";
    protected const string pack_bg_name = "pack_bg";
    protected const string background_name = "background";
    protected const string foreground_name = "foreground";

    protected const string shortcut_prefab_name = "Shortcut.prefab";
    protected const string dialog_prefab_name = "Dialog.prefab";

    #endregion

    protected abstract void CreateOffer();

    protected void CreateFolders(string offerPath) {
        if (!Directory.Exists(offerPath + $"/{shortcut_folder_name}")) {
            AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(AssetDatabase.CreateFolder(offerPath, shortcut_folder_name));
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(offerPath + $"/{dialog_folder_name}")) {
            AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(AssetDatabase.CreateFolder(offerPath, dialog_folder_name));
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(offerPath + $"/{shortcut_folder_name}/{images_folder_name}")) {
            AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(AssetDatabase.CreateFolder(offerPath + $"/{shortcut_folder_name}", images_folder_name));
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(offerPath + $"/{dialog_folder_name}/{images_folder_name}")) {
            AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(AssetDatabase.CreateFolder(offerPath + $"/{dialog_folder_name}", images_folder_name));
        }
    }
    
    protected void MoveTexture(Texture2D tex, string path, string newName) {
        if (tex == null) {
            return;
        }

        AssetDatabase.MoveAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(tex), $"{path}/{newName}.png");
    }

    protected GameObject CreatePrefabVariant(string prefabOriginPath, string prefabVariantPath) {
        var prefabVariant = (GameObject) AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(prefabVariantPath, typeof(GameObject));
        if (prefabVariant != null) {
            return prefabVariant;
        }

        var prefabOrigin = (GameObject) AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(prefabOriginPath, typeof(GameObject));
        var objSource = PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(prefabOrigin) as GameObject;
        prefabVariant = PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(objSource, prefabVariantPath);
        DestroyImmediate(objSource);
        
        return prefabVariant;
    }

    protected void SetProperty(Object go, string propertyName, object obj) {
        SerializedObject so = new SerializedObject(go);
        var property = so.FindProperty(propertyName);
        if (property == null) {
            FFLogger.LogError($"Cannot find property {propertyName} in object: {go.name}");
            return;
        }
        so.Update();
        property.SetValue(obj);
        so.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
    
    protected void SetAddressableGroup(Object obj, string assetName, string groupName) {
        var settings = AddressableAssetSettingsDefaultObject.Settings;

        if (settings) {
            var group = settings.FindGroup(groupName);
            if (group != null) {
                var assetPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(obj);
                var guid = AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID(assetPath);

                var entry = settings.CreateOrMoveEntry(guid, group, false, false);
                entry.address = assetName;

                var entriesAdded = new List<AddressableAssetEntry> { entry };
                group.SetDirty(AddressableAssetSettings.ModificationEvent.EntryMoved, entriesAdded, false, true);
                settings.SetDirty(AddressableAssetSettings.ModificationEvent.EntryMoved, entriesAdded, true, false);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to google this but didn't found anything useful.
And here is how the prefab eventualy looks.
[Final prefab view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7O2b.png)